# Task(text classification) Based Embedding Overfit occurs with few hidden units

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, word2vec

Dataset: Ted dataset (provided as part of [assignment-2 of Oxford NLP 2017](https://github.com/oxford-cs-deepnlp-2017/practical-2)).

Task: Learn word embedding while performing text classification using Tensorflow.

Issue: Facing Overfitting even with below 5 hidden units whereas the data size is batch of (50 sample (textual content) and each sample is of 500x50 (sentence_length x Embed_dim). 
The number of batches = 33
sentence_length = 500

Note: Unseen words (in glove dict) and padding(if max_len < 500) are Zero Embedded.

Explain why it overfits though the complexity of model is lesser when compared to the task ?

Method:
Preprocess the text by keeping only alphabets and removed unknown words as well as mostly and least commonly used words. 
Used corresponding word’s Glove vectors as word embed which are trainable. 
The Data was trained to classify the texts into 8 (mutually exclusive) classes. 
Note: Overfitting occurs even after performing Dropout.

Model:

```py
x = embedding(text) #Glove Vectors used (trainable) [Glove.6B][2]
h = tanh(Wx + b)
u = Vh + c
p = softmax(u)
if testing:
    prediction = arg maxy’ py’ 
else: # training, with y as the given gold label
    loss = -log(py) # cross entropy criterion
```

Comment: Will attach code if required.

Comment: [2] in the question refers to Global vectors from Stanford NLP.